How to install AtomicParsley on Ubuntu?
From their official Github repo (https://github.com/wez/atomicparsley) they say:
Linux (x86-64):

Download the AtomicParsleyLinux.zip file and extract AtomicParsley

And then what? What do I do with the AtomicParsley file to actually install it? So that other programs can use it when they run?
